# Maurey-Pisier Theorem for complex Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

A famous theorem of Maurey and Pisier, usually stated for real Banach spaces, says that $\ell_a$ and $\ell_b$ are finitely representable in $X$, where $a$ is the supremum of the $p$ such that $X$ has Rademacher type $p$ and $b$ is the infimum of the $q$ such that $X$ has Rademacher cotype $q$. After reading 
[Banach-Mazur distance to complex $\ell^1$ of a space containing real $\ell^1$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/157228)
I'm somewhat puzzled. Is Maurey-Pisier Theorem valid when the scalar field is $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Did you try to fill in the details in my answer to that question?  That gives only $4+\epsilon$ finite representability, but I suggested how you might get $1+\epsilon$ finite representability.

Comment: I have to admit that I was unable to complete a proof based on your suggestions. I'll keep on trying. Thanks.

Comment: @Johnson. Where is the proof? I am very curious to k ow the answer.